# How can i use an affix when navbar reaches bottom of a certain div and also when it reaches the top of the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**Situation**

I have a navbar that first needs to be fixed and scroll with the page. Then when it reaches the bottom of a certain div i need it to be absolute en stay at the exact position. Then when the navbar reaches the top of the screen I need it to stick to the top. I can get 2 out of 3 steps to work, but never the third.

**Question**

How can i use an affix when navbar reaches bottom of a certain div and also when it reaches the top of the screen.

**Code - CSS**

```
  .navbar {
    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    &.affix {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
    }
  }

#affix2{
  position: relative !important;
  &.affix {
    .navbar {
    }
  }
}
```

**Code - HTML**

```
<div id="affix2" data-spy="affix">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <h6>
                <a href="/">Project</a>
                </h6>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-scrollers">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    //Here are all navbar items
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="item img-responsive">
        <img src="/img/ai_1.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="overlay_ai">
        <h3>NIEUW PROJECT</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Code - Script**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('body').scrollspy({ target: '#navbar-scrollers', offset: 120 });

        $('nav.navbar').affix({
            offset: {
                top: function () {
                    return (this.top = ($('.item').outerHeight(true) - $('nav.navbar').outerHeight(true)))
                }
            }
        });

        $('#affix2').affix({
            offset: {
                top: function () {
                    return (this.top = ($('.item').outerHeight(true) - $('nav.navbar').outerHeight(true)))
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

So basically I need the navbar to be Position: Fixed, then it has to be Absolute and then Fixed again.